# Gravity Forms: Limit entries by number of times of a certain field value and date

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I am trying to accomplish the following:

- User gets email with a special "company code" and URL
- By clicking on the URL, he gets redirected to a form where the company code is pre populated.
- **Now this form can be submitted with the same value (in this case 123) only 5 times, from 01/05/2017 to 31/05/2017 (this point is where I need help or guidance)**
- If above rules are correct, the user gets redirected to another more extensive form.

Now this is just an example scenario.

I have tried to accomplish something similar with the coupon codes, that seem to have the exact functionality I want (Usage Limit and Expire date), but the coupon field can't be pre populated I think, and needs an extra "Apply" confirmation from the user (+ some pricing and total that I don't need). I also need to pass on that specific value (=company code); to the next form

Comment: Since this is a premium plugin, please contact the authors for support. :)

Comment: They said to me it needed some custom solution they can't provide. That's why I'm trying here, to see if somebody can point me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with my [GW Submission Limits](https://gravitywiz.com/better-limit-submission-per-time-period-by-user-or-ip/). It supports limiting by any number of submissions for almost any time period and can be filtered by field value.

**Update**

To more specifically address your scenario, here's a query that will return the entry count for one of your values.

```
SELECT count( l.id ) FROM wp_rg_lead l
INNER JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail ld on ld.lead_id = l.id
WHERE MONTH( date_created ) = 5 
AND YEAR( date_created ) = YEAR( CURDATE() )
AND ld.field_number = 5
AND ld.value = 'Hello!'
```

Comment: Yes, I saw your solution, which seems great! But from what I understood it will not work for my needs.
For ex. I have a  field "Company number". The form can be submitted 3 times if the field value = 123 during the month of May; and 5 times if the field value is 124, during another period of time.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, I see. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Trying to integrate that in your GW Submission Limits, but no luck. Could you help me on the way please?
Thank you :)

Comment: The query is not intended to be used with GW Submission Limits. It's just the specific query you would need to get the number of entries submitted for a specified value in a specified month (May). You would need to use that in combination with gform_get_form_filter to hide the form and the gform_validation filter to throw a validation error when the limit is exceeded.